# seting a title, font size and color same time

Tags: html, fonts, size, title

guys I started coding html just 1 hour ago (I'm a high school student and I know nothing) and I'm looking for seting a title, font size and color but same time. I looked up everywhere for solution but I couldn't find it. Can you help me [**that's what I use for format**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfyU7.png)

Comment: "I'm a high school student and I know nothing" — You should be reading introductory tutorials (the ones on MDN are good) before resorting to Stackoverflow.

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or of [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are not very helpful. Put a [mcve] and (if applicable) text of the exception in the question itself. The editor has buttons and [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help you format it so it is readable. Provide a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) if you're asking about HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

Answer (score -2):

I took a look at your code, and there are some things wrong in your syntax. Your code:

```
<h1 font size = "5" color = #ff1794 > title="That's the title"> Title </font></h1>
```

The right way to do this, nowadays, is using CSS, because the tag **font** is not supported in HTML5. (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp).

You can do something like this:

```html
<h1 style="font-size:26px; color:#ff1794">That's the title</h1>
```

As you mentioned you're a high-school student and still do not know with HTML, I suggest you some online courses, if you google "HTML & CSS online courses" you'll get a lot of good suggestions and, certainly, in a couple of weeks you'll acquire a nice knowledge :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I can understand where I am wrong. Probably reason is looking for solution in different websites.I know I am bad at it for now but I'll get better.